# Completely standalone Clang on Linux

Tags: clang

Is it possible to have Clang be completely standalone on Linux system, even if using `libc++` and `libc++abi` requires linkage to `libgcc_s`?

Comment: Do you mean a statically linked binary with no .so (or .dll) dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not possible right now.

Some things like [glibc](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2014-05/msg00400.html) or the [linux kernel](http://llvm.linuxfoundation.org/index.php/Main_Page) do not build with `clang` (yet).

You can get rid of `libgcc_s` by linking your `libc++-abi` against `compiler-rt`, instead of `libgcc`.